# whats the use of storing image name while saving image into bytea column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, bytea

I am storing images into bytea column in postgresql my doubt is there any use if i store the file name example(tree.jpeg) into DB. Anyhow i'm able to display images in jsp which are stored in bytea column without its file name. so whats the use of storing file name of the images in DB?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason whatsoever to store the file name, unless you intend to store the image back in the file system under it's original name at some point.